Angular error: 1. If 'mat-card-actions' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
When I compile I get the following error:

If ‘mat-card’ is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If ‘mat-card’ is a Web Component then add ‘CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA’ to the ‘@NgModule.schemas’ of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

I imported everything correctly with app.module.ts I don’t know why I’m getting this?
My github:
https://github.com/chrisspenceratx/myFlix-Angular-client

Well the problem lies in how you generated your Angular project, and how you're trying to use it.
Your project was generated using Angular's standalone components and standalone bootstraping which DOES NOT uses an NgModule to boostrap the application :
Here's you main.ts :
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

The bootstrapApplication function is used to create an Angular app using a component, the AppComponent is used to bootstrap the application and your AppModule is entirely ignored, rendering the imports you made inside it useless.
To fix this problem you can either convert the rest of your application to standalone component and get rid of your app.module, or bootstrap the application using the bootstrapModule function.
Here's what you can replace your main.ts with :
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

This should fix the import errors.

Thank you so much that fixed the import errors!  I'm now getting a standalone error though.  Can you please tell me what to do now?  The error is:
NG0907: The _AppComponent component is not marked as standalone, but Angular expects to have a standalone component here. Please make sure the _AppComponent component has the standalone: true flag in the decorator.

I'd say it probably comes from the server side of your application, as it is also configured as  standalone.
I would advise you to either switch to standalone component or regenerate your application without standalone.

Can you please look at my current github?  I entered standalone: true for all of my pages with @Component and it still won't work (I can't share a screenshot in this comment otherwise I would).  I now get this in my terminal:  TS-996008: Component AppComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule. Did you mean to import it instead? [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/app.module.ts:21:8:
  21 │         AppComponent,


I thought entering the standalone: true statements would switch it to standalone, do I need to do something else?

I just started over without standalone and everythings working now.  thank you for your help!

I'm glad this fixed your problem, could you accept the answer so the question is closed ?

I clicked the check mark, does that accept the answer?  Never posted on stackoverflow so i'm not sure
